# Balena Etcher will not Detect USB Drive on eOS

Tags: usb-drive, usb

I recently just installed Elementary and I don't really enjoy it. I'm trying to flash my USB drive with BalenaEtcher to switch to a different distro, but it won't detect my USB drive, I don't know what to do to make it detect it, Any ideas?

Comment: Does the USB device appear anywhere else in the system, such as the file manager? 

Comment: Yeah it shows in the files, but not in the etcher all while selecting target.